# Unable to receive to verify the stream configuration for Google cross account protection (RISC)

Tags: secevents

I've had my event endpoint setup and also configured the event stream. However, when testing my stream configuration, I got 200 for sending authorized HTTPS POST request to https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify but I'm not able to receive any thing on my endpoint.
Here is what I did, I configured the event stream via sending auth token to https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update with my endpoint url and also `https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/verification`, and I got 200 back.
Then, I tested via sending a post request to https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify . But I didn't get anything on my receiver endpoint. I'm also able to call getStream and getStreamStatus to verify that my endpoint is registered and enbaled. Am I missing anything here?

Also, I'm a little bit confused about the permission management here. We have different OAuth clients setup in our project. Do we need different service account for each OAuth client or one is enough to manage all OAuth clients as long as they are all under the same project?